# Angular material mat-slide-toggle change toggle icon

Tags: angular, angular-material, google-material-icons

I am using angular6 to layout my UI.

The default mat-slide-toggle button looks like this:

[image]

But i want the toggle button to look like below from the material-icons toggle_on , toggle_off

[image]

Is it possible to customize it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to use `mat-slide-toggle` if you want to replace it with your own widget? You can change the color of material design widgets. Is that not enough?

Comment: because i don't need to implement the checked binding , change  trigger...etc by using mat-slide-toggle. Actually i am very new to angular. I just start step into this field and being assigned to do that.

Comment: What do you mean? You will still have to implement checked binding and change trigger if you want that with mat-slide-toggle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could overwrite the default styling that is being applied to the Material [slide toggle component](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview). I must warn you, this is a bit hacky to do so. However, here's my take on your screenshot.

[image: Slide toggle example]

Styling that is needed for this:

```css
.mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    width: 10px !important;
    height: 10px !important;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}

.mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  height: 16px !important;
}

.mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container {
  top: -2px !important;
}

.mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  background-color: #000;
}

.mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Unfortunately, some `!important` is needed to overrule the default styling that is set by Angular's Material CSS. You can view the **[example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6zstfr?file=styles.css)**.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this one.

Answer (score 3):

I got into this question when I wanted to know how to add an icon in the center of the material mat-slide-toggle

## How to add icon in the center of material slide toggle?

We need to slide toggle has a icon in the center of it *(here you see Google Crhome icon in the center of the toggle button)*, something like the image bellow:

[image]

What you'll need to do is to set your desired image (as an icon) as background-image of the toggle button (`.mat-slide-toggle-thumb`)

```
.mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    width: 18px !important;
    height: 18px !important;
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-round-system/512/chrome_browser-512.png) !important;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
}

.mat-accent .mat-slide-toggle-thumb{
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.mat-checked .mat-slide-toggle-thumb{
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

**Here is the [working example demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-slide-custom-icon?file=styles.css)**

*Note: I used the code snippet provided by the accepted answer.*

Answer (score 2):

**Theming**

The color of a  can be changed by using the color property. By default, slide-toggles use the theme's accent color. This can be changed to 'primary' or 'warn'.

You can change the css for the same using the rule

```
mat-slide-toggle:not(.mat-checked):not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  background-color: black; /* set your color here */
}
```

You could also set different colors based on the type:

```
 mat-slide-toggle.mat-primary:not(.mat-checked):not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  background-color: pink;
}

mat-slide-toggle.mat-accent:not(.mat-checked):not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the color. I want to change the icon look.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/slide-toggle/_slide-toggle-theme.scss
you can view this scss for slide toggle and mix and match for your result

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav Kumar Goyal. I will check at that scss.